# print space instead of integer

Tags: c, char, ascii, cs50, c-strings

here is the code

```c
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {

    string text = get_string ("plaintext:");

    for (int i=0; text[i] !='\0'; i++) {

        int s = (int) text[i];

        printf ("%i ",s);

    }

    printf("\n");

}
```

and here is the expected output of this

```
./scrabbleee
plaintext:this is a string
116 104 105 115 32 105 115 32 97 32 115 116 114 105 110 103
```

How to stop space 32 ascii value to print?  Can I print space instead of 32?

Comment: Use a conditional statement, like `if (s != 32) { ... }`.

Answer (score 2):

In C there is the standard function `isblank`  that determines whether the given character is the space character `' '` or the tab character `'\t'`.

So you can write

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {

    string text = get_string( "plaintext: " );

    for ( size_t i = 0; text[i] !='\0'; i++ ) {

        if ( isblank( ( unsigned char )text[i] ) )
        {
            printf( "%c ", ' ' );
        }
        else
        {  
            printf ( "%i ", text[i] );
        }

    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

So if a tab or space character will be encountered in a string then the space character `' '` will be outputted.

Pay attention to that there is no need to cast a character to the type `int` like

```
int s = (int) text[i];
```

before the call

```
printf ( "%i ", text[i] );
```

because due to the integer promotions the character will be promoted to the type `int` implicitly.

Also it is desirable to change this statement

```
printf ( "%i ", text[i] );
```

to

```
printf ( "%i ", ( unsigned char)text[i] );
```

if you want to output all values of characters as unsigned values. In this case the program will not depend on the used character set ASCII or EBCDIC.

And never use magic numbers like `32` as it is advised in other answers.:)

Comment: Re “due to the integer promotions”: The integer promotions are not applied to either operand of `=`. The right operand is converted to the type the left operand would have after lvalue conversion.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The integer promotion is used in the call of printf.

Answer (score 0):

You can display it as a character if it's 32:

```
if (s != 32) {
    printf ("%i ",s);
} else {
    printf ("%c ",s);
}
```

I did not work with C for a looong time, but if you can use the ternary operator for strings, then you can do this as well:

```
printf((s != 32) ? "%i " : "%c ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer to the question including @Lajos's answer.
There are only two cases, so print 'space' or none 'space'

```
#include <cs50.h>                         
#include <stdio.h>                        
#include <string.h>                       
                                          
int main (void) {                                             
  string text = get_string ("plaintext:");
  for (int i=0; text[i] !='\0'; i++){     
    int s = (int) text[i];                
    printf ((s != 32)? "%i ": " ", s);    
  }                                       
  printf("\n");                           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
    if (s == ' ')
        printf(" ", s);
    else
        printf ("%i ",s);
```

other:

```
    printf(s == ' ' ? " " : "%i ", s);
```

another:

```
    switch (s) {
    case ' ': printf(" "); break;
    default: printf("%i ", s); break;
    /* other cases */
    }
```

another more:

You have a table of strings telling how do you want each character to be written:

```
char *toStrin[256] = { "0", "1", "2"...., " ", "!", "33", ... "A", "B", "C", 
    ..., "DEL", "128", "129", ... }; 


    printf("%s ", toString[s]);
```

in my opinion, the last one is the most flexible, as you can decide, for each caracter, how do you want it printed.